# How to send HTML content in form data to avoid CSRF warnings

Tags: http, post, aws-api-gateway, csrf, amazon-waf

In one of my application, I need to send the HTML (generated by user by using rich-text editor) to the server. This HTML needs to go along with an attachment. So, I am sending the HTML string along with a attachment in the form data of a multipart request.

This works fine technically. However, when I shipped the code to production, the REST API started throwing 403. Further analysis revealed that the REST call was blocked by the AWS WAF policies applied on the Production's API gateway. The WAF cited the following rule to block the request.

`AWS#AWSManagedRulesCommonRuleSet#CrossSiteScripting_BODY`

My question is, Is there a secured way of sending the HTML content in the POST body that will avoid violating this error.

I tried searching for this but could not find any reliable content. Any suggestions/documentation would really help me here.

Comment: Uploading the attachment as base64 string instead of uploading as multipart/form-data should fix the issue.

Comment: @ragnar Its not the attachment, rather the HTML string that is causing the issue. Anyways, will try encoding the HTML once